# Visualforce page submit button doesnt work after "rendered"

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

I have a problem with my visualforce page. Currently I am trying to switch pages based on SelectOption. If selected option is French I need to translate everything to french. Currently this functionality is working, but another is not working. Based on some url parameters, clients have submission form.
After clicking the submit button, I do some DMLs. That used to work before, but after putting  or  funtionallity doesnt work.[image: <code>Page</code>]

Here it is my method. ` public  PageReference doSubmit(){
        if(userInput==NULL || userInput=='' ){

```
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Fail'));

    }
    else{
        String caseId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
        List<case> caseForUpdate = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE IV_EncryptedId__c=:caseId];
        if (caseForUpdate.size()>0) {
           String postBody = 'Customer feedback on Case rejection: '+userInput;
            createPlatformEvent(caseForUpdate[0].Id,postBody);
        }
        System.debug('here');
        isShown = true;
        hasSecondMessage = true;
        hasFinished = true;
    }

    return null;
}`
```

and visualforce page `<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!isEnglish}">
            <div class="message-box">
                <p class="messsage">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!!hasVisited && !isInvalid}">
                        <h1>Thank you for your feedback.</h1>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!hasVisited && !isInvalid}">
                        <h1>Thank you for visiting us again.</h1>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!displayMessage}"/>
                    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!!isShown}">
                        <apex:inputTextArea value="{!userInput}" style="width: 360px; height: 190px; margin-top: 10px" /><br/>
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!doSubmit}" value="Send Feedback"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!hasSecondMessage}">
                        Your Case will be reviewed again by a Service Consultant as soon as possible.
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!isInvalid}">
                        <h1> Invalid Link.</h1>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </p>
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlock>`

Comment: Jeni, please paste only the relevant parts of your code, and paste it all here (not in pastebin). I tried to copy the pastebin code here and I exceeded the list allowed by SFSE.... To be frank, most people will not read that wall of text, but a lot of us would be happy to try an help based on a relevant blurb. Thanks and good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot, @SebastianKessel